# How to resize my paragraph based on number of characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have my text fitted in my div.
So I have a 140px default text size and In some cases I want to use a span (like in my example) to force text to stay on one line and more text under this.

My block-a and block-b must have the height from the text but no more than 1000px.

Also, I have a fixed width on the divs with 100px padding. If my "one line text" is longer than the div, must resize to fit.

What I do wrong ?

```js
;(function($) {
    $.fn.textfill = function(options) {
        var fontSize = options.maxFontPixels;
        var ourText = $('span', this);
        var maxHeight = $(this).height();
        var maxWidth = $(this).width();
        var textHeight;
        var textWidth;
  console.log(maxHeight);
  console.log(maxWidth);


        do {
            ourText.css('font-size', fontSize);
            textHeight = ourText.height();
            textWidth = ourText.width();
            fontSize = fontSize - 1;
        } while ((textHeight > maxHeight || textWidth > maxWidth) && fontSize > 4);
        return this;
    }
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#blocka').textfill({ maxFontPixels: 140 });
    $('#blockb').textfill({ maxFontPixels: 140 });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
    /* don't touch */
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.blocks {
    /* here is the maximum width of the container. if you change the width of a and b and they have together more than 3000px, you have to change it from here too */
    width: 3000px;

    /* don't touch */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;

    /* if you change the max height of the boxes a and b below. you have to put here the same value from there */
    height: 1000px;

    /* dont touch */
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #ff0;
}

.block-a, .block-b {
    /* here is the width of the block a and block b. they are linked together */
    width: 800px;

    /* here is the padding of the blocks a and b linked together */
    padding: 100px;

    /* Here is the align of the text from box a and b. values available: left, center, right */
    text-align: center;

    /* from here you can change the max height of the boxes a and b */
    max-height: 1000px;

    /* don't touch */
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ddd;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.blocks span {
 display: block;
 
    font-size:140px;
    /* if you want to put some font family, you can do it from here. In this case, we use Arial with fallbacks Verdana and sans-serif */
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;

    /* don't touch */
    line-height: 1;
    color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FitText.js/1.2.0/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="blocks">
        <div class="block-a" id="blocka" style="width: 800px; height: 800px;">
   <span style="white-space: nowrap;" class="first">!Test Test Test!!!!</span>
            <span class="second">Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test</span>

        </div>

        <div class="block-b" id="blockb" style="width: 800px; height: 800px;">
   <span>
   Test Testaaa
   </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does this mean? _to force text to stay on one line and more text under this_? You are setting static values for height and width (800px) and then never changing them...they are always 800px.

Comment: I mean I want to put a <span style="white-space: nowrap;" class="first">!Test Test Test!!!!</span> and under this to continue with more text

Comment: I realize in your mind, this: _and under this to continue with more text_ means something specific. But we don't know if you mean "text within the span" or "text within another element within the span" or "in a span under this span" or "text beneath the span with no element wrapper", etc. Do you see? Please be explicit.

Comment: You can see whant I want from my code:
<span style="white-space: nowrap;" class="first">!Test Test Test!!!!</span>
            <span class="second">Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test</span>

Comment: @StefanIordache what do you mean by `What I do wrong ?` it's working fine

Comment: Exactly! That question is still the question

Comment: I got this result https://prnt.sc/l6qt67  and seems to not fit in height

Comment: and I dont find the way to do this .. i think i should do with getComputedStyle but I dont know how